# Custom height of a MDBInput in react

Tags: reactjs, mdbootstrap

I'll like to make a MDBInput smaller. I have :

```
<MDBInput className="w-100 p-3 h-25" type="text" label="URL Enunciat" name="name" value={quiz.name} />
```

but I'll like to reduce also the height and font size. but how?

tried that:

```
.test1{
height:30px;
font-size:9px;
}
<MDBInput className="test1" type="text" label="URL Enunciat" name="name" value={quiz.name} />
```

but did not work!

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to add a custom CSS class or `style` attr?

Comment: yes, but did not work